# Interpreting the statement based on the situation

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

I got a statement like this today "I am also to blame here" - Does it means the guy came to blame us? or He is also part of the blame?

Also could you please help me to frame the sentence in the both case.

- How to frame this statement if the guy came to blame a group of
  people?
- How to frame a sentence if he is also part of the blame and he is accepting in a group.

Please help to correct this.?

Answer (score 1):

It means that he is also taking some of the blame.

To frame your two sentences:

- "You are all to blame here"
- "We're all to blame here" / "We all have to take some of the blame here" / "I'm also to blame here"

Answer (score 1):

"Here" does not always refer to a literal location - it can also refer to a present *situation*.

"I am also to blame *here*" means that they consider themselves also to blame for the present situation, or for the matter presently being discussed.